# Incomprehensible technical interview

Tags: string

This was a question asked in a recent programming interview.

> Given a string "str" and pair of "N" swapping indices, generate a lexicographically largest string. Swapping indices can be reused any number times.

Eg:

```
String = "abdc" 
Indices: 
(1,4) 
(3,4)
```

Answer:

```
cdba, cbad, dbac,dbca
```

> You should print only "dbca" which is lexicographically largest.

This might sound naive, but I completely fail to follow the question. Can someone please help me understand what the question means?

Comment: Down voter what's your argument?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: Simply sort your string in descending order like it is an array of numbers

Comment: @LibertyPaul: That doesn't meet the requirements. Given a string `"abcd"` and a single pair of indices `(3, 4)`, you can only get `"abcd"` and `"abdc"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's saying that, given the string `mystring = "abdc"`, you are instructed to switch characters at the specified index pairs such that you produce the lexicographically "largest" string (i.e. such that if you [lex-sorted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) all possible strings, it would end up at the last index). So you have two valid operations: (1) switch `mystring[1]` with `mystring[4]` (`"abdc"` --> `"cbda"`), and (2)  switch `mystring[3]` with `mystring[4]` (`"abdc"` --> `"abcd"`). Also, you can multiply chain operations: either operation (1) followed by (2) (`"abdc"` --> `"cbda"` --> `"cbad"`), or vice versa (`"abdc"` -->  `"abcd"` --> `"dbca"`), and so on and so forth (`"abdc"` --> `"cbda"` --> `"cbad"` --> `"dbac"`).

Then you (reverse) lex-sort these and pop off the top index:

```
>>> allPermutations = ['abcd', 'cbad', 'abdc', 'cbda', 'dbca', 'dbac']
>>> lexSorted = sorted(allPermutations, reverse=True) # ['dbca', 'dbac', 'cbda', 'cbad', 'abdc', 'abcd']
>>> lexSorted.pop(0)
'dbca'
```

Comment: OK, so shouldn't the char corresponding  to mystring[1] be b and mystring[4] be `indexOutOfBound`

Comment: @Zeus I'm assuming they're indexing starting at 1 (like Matlab) and not at 0 (like Python). So `mystring[1]` would be `'a'` and `mystring[4]` would be `'c'`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the clarification by @ncemami I came up with this solution.

```
public static String swap(String str, Pair<Integer, Integer> p1, Pair<Integer, Integer> p2){

        TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<>();
        String s1 = swap(str, p1.getKey(), p1.getValue());
        set.add(s1);
        String s2 = swap(s1, p2.getKey(), p2.getValue());
        set.add(s2);
        String s3 = swap(str, p2.getKey(), p2.getValue());
        set.add(s3);
        String s4 = swap(s3, p1.getKey(), p1.getValue());
        set.add(s4);
        return set.last();

    }
    private static String swap(String str, int a, int b){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        char temp1 = str.charAt(a);
        char temp2 = str.charAt(b);
        sb.setCharAt(a, temp2);
        sb.setCharAt(b, temp1);
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my Java solution:

```
String swapLexOrder(String str, int[][] pairs) {
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> neighbours = new HashMap<>();

for (int[] pair : pairs) {
    // It contains all the positions that are reachable from the index present in the pairs
    Set<Integer> reachablePositionsL = neighbours.get(pair[0]);
    Set<Integer> temp = neighbours.get(pair[1]); // We use it just to merge the two sets if present

    if (reachablePositionsL == null) {
        reachablePositionsL = (temp == null ? new TreeSet<>() : temp);
    } else if (temp != null) {
        // Changing the reference so every addition to "reachablePositionsL" will reflect on both positions
        for (Integer index: temp) {
            neighbours.put(index, reachablePositionsL);
        }
        reachablePositionsL.addAll(temp);
    }
    reachablePositionsL.add(pair[0]);
    reachablePositionsL.add(pair[1]);
    neighbours.put(pair[0], reachablePositionsL);
    neighbours.put(pair[1], reachablePositionsL);
}

StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str);
for (Set<Integer> set : neighbours.values()) {
    Iterator<Character> orderedCharacters = set.stream()
        .map(i -> str.charAt(i - 1))
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .iterator();

    set.forEach(i -> result.setCharAt(i - 1, orderedCharacters.next()));
}
return result.toString();
}
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@andrey.khayrutdinov/find-the-largest-string-permutation-given-allowed-swaps-c5150cd5ad88) an article that explain my the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
String = "abcd"

co_ord = [(1,4),(3,4)]

def find_combinations(co_ord, String):

    l1 = []
    for tup_le in co_ord:
        l1.extend(tup_le)
    l1 = [x-1 for x in l1]
    l1 = list(set(l1))
    l2 = set(range(len(String)))-set(l1)
    return l1,int(''.join(str(i) for i in l2))

def perm1(lst):

    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    else:
        l = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            x = lst[i]
            xs = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
            for p in perm1(xs):
                l.append([x]+p)
        return l

lx, ly = find_combinations(co_ord, String)    

final = perm1(lx)

print(final)

temp = []

final_list=[]

for i in final:

    for j in i:

        temp.append(String[j])

    final_list.append(''.join(temp))

    temp=[]

final_list = [ i[:ly] + String[ly] + i[ly:] for i in final_list]    

print(sorted(final_list,reverse=True)[0])
```